# How to put <div> tags on opposite sides of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website, which contains a game. The instructions area is supposed to be on the right side of the screen, and the upgrades area is supposed to be on the left. Right now, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tbru3z96/) is what I have.

(please don't comment on anything besides the `div` tags, I know I'm messing up the sizes)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Cookie Clicker</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Roboto|Roboto+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Cookie Clicker</h1>
<br>
<div class=game><!--Game-->
<div class='text1'><!--Instructions-->
<h2>Instructions</h2>
<p>Cookie Clicker is a game about clicking a big cookie to earn points, and using those points to buy upgrades which give you cookies.</p>
</div><!--/Instructions-->
<div class='upgrades'><!--Upgrades-->
<p>ttttt</p>
</div><!--/Upgrades-->
</div><!--/Game-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In CSS, `position: fixed` will lock an element in position on the screen, ignoring page scrolling. You can combine this with positional properties like `left` and `right` to change where it's "locked". Something like `.upgrades { position: fixed; left: 0; }` should nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: hello are you familiar with css flexbox? If you want, I can apply the changes to your code if you want to use flexbox :)

Comment: @reiallenramos just do it and post an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRayen's answer didn't look like it actually accomplished what you wanted, so take a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tbru3z96/8/).

I did a few things:

1. Moved the `upgrades` div out of the `text1` div so they are both
   direct children of the `game` div
2. Set `game` to have a display value of `flexbox`, which is a new-ish CSS layout technique that really helps with this style of design.
3. Gave both upgrade and instruction boxes a `flex-basis` of 20%, which is similar to your width: 20%;
4. Removed the margin-right on `upgrades`

I highly recommend looking into [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for more info on how to create and edit layouts like this!

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes to the CSS:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding: 15px
}

.text1 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1.4px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20em;
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
}

.mono {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.upgrades {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1.4px solid grey; 
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20em;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Cookie Clicker</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Roboto|Roboto+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>Cookie Clicker</h1>
      <br>
      <div class=game><!--Game-->
        <div class='text1'><!--Instructions-->
            <h2>Instructions</h2>
              <p>Cookie Clicker is a game about clicking a big cookie to earn points, and using those points to buy upgrades which give you cookies.</p>
            </div><!--/Instructions-->
            <div class='upgrades'><!--Upgrades-->
              <p>ttttt</p>
            </div><!--/Upgrades-->
        </div><!--/Game-->
    </body>
  </html>
```